# First exception on row 0 with id 0067F000006pmy7QAA; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

```
@isTest
public class TestUpdate {
    static testMethod void validateStage() {
        Opportunity opp=new Opportunity(Name='OPP', StageName='Closed-Won', CloseDate = System.today()+1, TotalOpportunityQuantity = 1);
        insert opp;
        Opportunity testOLI = new Opportunity(Id = opp.Id);
        insert testOLI;
        opp.StageName = 'Closed-Won';
        Test.startTest();
        update opp;
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In these lines:

```
    Opportunity testOLI = new Opportunity(Id = opp.Id);
    insert testOLI;
```

you "specify Id in an insert call" by setting the Id of the second Opportunity to the Id of the first Opportunity. Remove those lines.